# Link a domain name to my router's public IP

Tags: apache, raspberry-pi, ip, router

I have a raspberry pi that i use as a web server. I have an Apache server and I use my router's public address to access to my website.

Can i pay for a domain name and "link" it to my router's public IP ? Or will i always have to type the IP to go to my website ?

EDIT : thanks to the answers, i managed to do it. on ionos, you have to go on the dns settings of your domaine name and add your router ip for the 'A' type record for both '@' and 'www'. you will also have to add a domain name in your apache or nginx server to avoid the ip to appear in the user's web browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, Your computer is treated the same as any server, a few things you should do to make it work.

- Get a static IP. You need this so your domain will be pointing to the same IP always.
- Point your domain to the IP you got (with an A record)
- port forward your web port (80, 443, 8080 or any other port used by your web server) to the internal computer IP (192.168.X.X, 10.0.0.X, or any other)

Answer (score 1):

Yes to point your domain name to an IP address you can create an `A Record`.

You can see screenshots [here](https://www.name.com/support/articles/205188538-Pointing-your-domain-to-hosting-with-A-records)